# Function called in setTimeout not using current React state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

## quick summary

I'm trying to create a button that has both a regular click and a separate action that happens when a user clicks and holds it, similar to the back button in Chrome.

The way I'm doing this involves a `setTimeout()` with a callback that checks for something in state. For some reason, the callback is using state from the time that `setTimeout()` was called, and not at the time when it's callback is called (1 second later).

You can view it on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/5woy81983l)

## how I'm trying to accomplish this

In order to get this feature, I'm calling `setTimeOut()` onMouseDown. I also set isHolding, which is in state, to true.

onMouseUp I set isHolding to false and also run `clickHandler()`, which is a prop, if the hold function hasn't had time to be called.

The callback in `setTimeOut()` will check if isHolding is true, and if it is, it will run `clickHoldHandler()`, which is a prop.

## problem

isHolding is in state (I'm using hooks), but when `setTimeout()` fires it's callback, I'm not getting back the current state, but what the state was when `setTimetout()` was first called.

## my code

Here's how I'm doing it:

```
const Button = ({ clickHandler, clickHoldHandler, children }) => {
  const [isHolding, setIsHolding] = useState(false);
  const [holdStartTime, setHoldStartTime] = useState(undefined);
  const holdTime = 1000;

  const clickHoldAction = e => {
    console.log(`is holding: ${isHolding}`);
    if (isHolding) {
      clickHoldHandler(e);
    }
  };

  const onMouseDown = e => {
    setIsHolding(true);
    setHoldStartTime(new Date().getTime());

    setTimeout(() => {
      clickHoldAction(e);
    }, holdTime);
  };

  const onMouseUp = e => {
    setIsHolding(false);

    const totalHoldTime = new Date().getTime() - holdStartTime;
    if (totalHoldTime < holdTime || !clickHoldHandler) {
      clickHandler(e);
    }
  };

  const cancelHold = () => {
    setIsHolding(false);
  };

  return (
    <button
      onMouseDown={onMouseDown}
      onMouseUp={onMouseUp}
      onMouseLeave={cancelHold}
    >
      {children}
    </button>
  );
};
```

Comment: Whenever the component rerenders, all functions inside are recreated. `setTimeout` holds a reference to an "old" function that holds a reference to the "old" state.

Comment: Hi Zach, I would suggest looking at this article which explains the difference between functional and class components and how they capture state. https://overreacted.io/how-are-function-components-different-from-classes/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap that callback task into a reducer and trigger the timeout as an effect. Yes, that makes things certainly more complicated (but it's "best practice"):

```
  const Button = ({ clickHandler, clickHoldHandler, children }) => {
     const holdTime = 1000;
     const [holding, pointer] = useReducer((state, action) => {
        if(action === "down") 
           return { holding: true, time: Date.now()  };
        if(action === "up") {
          if(!state.holding)
              return { holding: false };
          if(state.time + holdTime > Date.now()) {
                clickHandler();
          } else {
                clickHoldHandler();
          }
          return { holding: false };
        }
        if(action === "leave")
          return { holding: false };
     }, { holding: false, time: 0 });

     useEffect(() => {
       if(holding.holding) {
         const timer = setTimeout(() => pointer("up"), holdTime - Date.now() + holding.time);
         return () => clearTimeout(timer);
       }
     }, [holding]);

     return (
       <button
         onMouseDown={() => pointer("down")}
         onMouseUp={() => pointer("up")}
         onMouseLeave={() => pointer("leave")}
       >
         {children}
        </button>
    );
  };
```

working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/7yn9xmx15j

---

As a fallback if the reducer gets too complicated, you could memoize an object of settings (not best practice):

```
 const state = useMemo({
   isHolding: false,
   holdStartTime: undefined,
 }, []);

 // somewhere
 state.isHolding = true;
```

Comment: @zach apologies for the mess, I definetly need sleep now ... and thanks for the edit :)

Comment: no problem, you made it 99% of the way there. I just swapped the two functions. 